# Overflow while using ReadWriteMemory

Tags: python, ram

I'm trying to fetch information from a hex editor. But ReadWriteMemory gives me an error about `"<class 'OverflowError'>: int too long to convert"`

Here is my code:

```
from ReadWriteMemory import ReadWriteMemory

base_address = 0x7FF6D60A0000
static_address_offset = 0x0074DE40
pointer_static_address = base_address + static_address_offset
offsets = [0x08, 0x08, 0xB0, 0x08, 0x278, 0x10, 0xD0]

rmw = ReadWriteMemory()
process = rmw.get_process_by_name('010Editor.exe')
process.open()
pointer = process.get_pointer(pointer_static_address, offsets=offsets)
pointer_value = process.read(pointer)
print(pointer_value)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The problem seems to be with the size of the base address? Can you use 48-bit addresses, and if not, where did you get the base address?

Comment: I found it using the pointers. So "010Editor.exe" + 0074DE40 = 7FF67709DE40. I extracted 0074DE40 from the total. Found 0x7FF6D60A0000. I don't know how to use 48-bit address. That's where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it using 'pymem', So it appears that ReadWriteMemory can't handle 64bit applications.

```
from pymem import *
from pymem.process import *

pm = Pymem('010Editor.exe')

def GetByteNumber():
    def GetPtrAddr(base, offsets):
        addr = pm.read_longlong(base)
        for i in offsets:
            if i != offsets[-1]:
                addr = pm.read_longlong(addr + i)
        return addr + offsets[-1]
    return pm.read_int(GetPtrAddr(pm.base_address + 0x0074DE40, offsets=[0x8, 0x8, 0x60, 0x8, 0x10, 0xB0, 0xD0]))
```

Comment: your solution give me two errors: `pymem.exception.WinAPIError: Windows api error, error_code: 299` and `pymem.exception.MemoryReadError: Could not read memory at: 280, length: 8 - GetLastError: 299`

Comment: @Jawad if you have error_code 299 that means you entered offset wrong. You need to enter offsets from last to first.